# Serving static file locally on a subdomain

Tags: node.js, vue.js, deployment, subdomain

I have a web application with a Vue front-end and Golang back-end.

I am trying to deploy the front-end static files on local work network.

I am serving them with http-server on a windows server connected to the network.

Rightnow if I execute

```
http-server -p 50
```

I am able to access the application by going to http://hostname:
50

However, the goal is to deploy it on

```
http://hostname/app
```

Is it possible to do it, if so what would be the approach in terms of best practices.

Note: For deployment of the Vue static files either a node server or golang server would work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Let's start with a bit of terminology correction.

- `http://hostname` is not really a domain. It is just a URL referring to
  an unqualified host name. A domain would typically be something like
  `yourorgdomain.com` (or `.org` or `.edu` or other such top level domains;
  let's stick with `.com` for now). Your hostname (when fully qualified
  under the domain) would be identified as `hostname.yourdomain.com`.
  Therefore, your hostname is mapped to a subdomain. For the sake of
  simplicity, if being referred from another host on the same domain
  and network the domain part is implied so the network understands that and something like `http://hostname` just works. The mapping is somewhere
  in your network configuration.
- `http://hostname/app` is not a subdomain of `http://hostname`; it's just
  a path (or more correctly a resource) under the same host `http://hostname`. A subdomain would be something like `http://app.hostname` `http://app.hostname.yourdomain.com` when fully qualified)

#### Now for some explanation of how these URLs work:

Consider the URL `http://hostname:50`. The `http://` part is referring to the protocol and `:50` part at the end to the port number. By default http uses port 80 (https uses 443). So if you configure your web server to serve on port 80, the `:50` part is redundant.

Now you just need to organize your website content such that it is available at `http://hostname/app` URL. The simplest way to do this for static sites is to host your content under the `/app/...` directory relative to where your site root is mapped to. So if your web server is serving the directory `.../public` on `http://hostname`, just move your content to `.../public/app` like you do for file paths. That's all

#### Caveats

However, if you truly want to host your app under a subdomain like `http://app.hostname/` then that's a whole different story, but in brief, the lowest level subdomain being referred to (app) has to be mapped to a host and the intermediate subdomain can't be a host, just a subnet. You can't have further subdomains under a host. That's why typically websites addresses refer to `http://www.example.com` where the `www` is mapped to the host actually running the website

All of this ignores how reverse proxies and load balancers work and pretend to exhibit this above behavior but that another long story for another day.